# CruiseControl.NET only shows one NUnit Assembly on NUnit Details page

Tags: nunit, cruisecontrol.net

I am using NUnit with CruiseControl.NET. I have many test projects and assemblies. When I run my tests, on the NUnit Details page, it only shows one assembly, but with all of the tests from all assemblies. In the log, it lists them as separate in the XML. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: I never noticed this before. Presumably this is a bug in the XSL file that is used to transform the XML results into the HTML report?

Comment: Same thing for me since I upgraded to the new CC.Net (1.5). I also think David White is right with his answer/hint. Did you find the solution in the meanwhile?

Comment: Same problem. It is only showing results from the first assembly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed this by listing the NUnit tasks separately in the MSBuild file and producing separate output files for each test assembly. Then in the CruiseControl configuration file I listed each output file in the merge section. This produced a nice result in the webdashboard for each test assembly.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me, but I am using 2 nunit tags in the cruise control config for the project.